# What about the differentiability of two conjugate mappings?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $f,g:M\rightarrow M$ be topologically conjugate(i.e., there exists a homeomorphism $h:M\rightarrow M$ such that $f\circ h=h\circ g$). If $f,g$ are differentiable, is it possible that $f,g$ have different order of differentiability?

Comment: $x \mapsto x^3$ and $x \mapsto x \cdot |x|$ on $\mathbb{R}$ are topologically conjugated.

Comment: @ D. Thomine, can you show me the conjugate transformation?

Comment: There is a standard recipe to construct them, see e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554908/show-two-interval-homeomorphisms-are-topologically-conjugate). Work separately on $(-\infty, -1]$, $[-1,0]$, $[0,1]$ and $[1, +\infty)$. Check that each conjugation fixes the endpoints (because $-1$ and $1$ are repelling for both $f$ and $g$, and $0$ is attracting for both), so you can glue the four conjugations you get.