# A question of conjugacy of Homeomorphism on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am studying analysis,I met a excercise as following. 
note $Homeo([0,1]):=\{f:[0,1]\to [0,1]|f\ is\ continuous\  bijection\}$.
Considers $f,g\in Homeo({0,1})$ which both have two fixed points $1$ and $0$.
Prove exists $h\in Homeo([0,1])$ s.t $h^{-1}fh\equiv  g$ .
I have no idea about how to prove it,can sb give me some idea?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Comment: Does this answer your question [Show two interval homeomorphisms are topologically conjugate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/554908/977780)

Comment: yes，great thanks